# How to work with ECW in GDAL?

Tags: gdal, ecw

I have `GDAL 2.4.2` plus ECW plugin.

```
gdalinfo --formats
>>ECW -raster- (rw): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 3.x)
```

And `gdalinfo` shows ecw file info.
But when i tried to use gdal2tiles i got error:

```
"C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal2tiles.py" -r near -a 0,0,0 -z 15 D:\OFP\input.ecw D:\dev\nginx-1.12.1\www\OFP

ERROR 4: `D:\OFP\input.ecw' not recognized as a supported file f
ormat.
Usage: gdal2tiles.py [options] input_file [output]

gdal2tiles.py: error: It is not possible to open the input file 'D:\OFP\input.ecw'.
```

What can be wrong here?

**UPDATE**

I found that gdal module do not know about this format:

```
from osgeo import gdal

driver_list = []
for i in range(gdal.GetDriverCount()):
    driver = gdal.GetDriver(i)
    driver_list.append(driver.GetDescription())

print(str(driver_list))

['VRT', 'DERIVED', 'GTiff', 'NITF', 'RPFTOC', 'ECRGTOC', 'HFA', 'SAR_CEOS', 'CEO
S', 'JAXAPALSAR', 'GFF', 'ELAS', 'AIG', 'AAIGrid', 'GRASSASCIIGrid', 'SDTS', 'DT
ED', 'PNG', 'JPEG', 'MEM', 'JDEM', 'GIF', 'BIGGIF', 'ESAT', 'BSB', 'XPM', 'BMP',
 'DIMAP', 'AirSAR', 'RS2', 'SAFE', 'PCIDSK', 'PCRaster', 'ILWIS', 'SGI', 'SRTMHG
T', 'Leveller', 'Terragen', 'ISIS3', 'ISIS2', 'PDS', 'PDS4', 'VICAR', 'TIL', 'ER
S', 'JP2OpenJPEG', 'L1B', 'FIT', 'GRIB', 'RMF', 'WCS', 'WMS', 'MSGN', 'RST', 'IN
GR', 'GSAG', 'GSBG', 'GS7BG', 'COSAR', 'TSX', 'COASP', 'R', 'MAP', 'KMLSUPEROVER
LAY', 'PDF', 'Rasterlite', 'MBTiles', 'PLMOSAIC', 'CALS', 'WMTS', 'SENTINEL2', '
MRF', 'PNM', 'DOQ1', 'DOQ2', 'PAux', 'MFF', 'MFF2', 'FujiBAS', 'GSC', 'FAST', 'B
T', 'LAN', 'CPG', 'IDA', 'NDF', 'EIR', 'DIPEx', 'LCP', 'GTX', 'LOSLAS', 'NTv1',
'NTv2', 'CTable2', 'ACE2', 'SNODAS', 'KRO', 'ROI_PAC', 'RRASTER', 'BYN', 'ARG',
'RIK', 'USGSDEM', 'GXF', 'NWT_GRD', 'NWT_GRC', 'ADRG', 'SRP', 'BLX', 'PostGISRas
ter', 'SAGA', 'IGNFHeightASCIIGrid', 'XYZ', 'HF2', 'OZI', 'CTG', 'E00GRID', 'ZMa
p', 'NGSGEOID', 'IRIS', 'PRF', 'RDA', 'EEDAI', 'EEDA', 'SIGDEM', 'GNMFile', 'GNM
Database', 'DB2ODBC', 'ESRI Shapefile', 'MapInfo File', 'UK .NTF', 'OGR_SDTS', '
S57', 'DGN', 'OGR_VRT', 'REC', 'Memory', 'BNA', 'CSV', 'NAS', 'GML', 'GPX', 'LIB
KML', 'KML', 'GeoJSON', 'GeoJSONSeq', 'ESRIJSON', 'TopoJSON', 'Interlis 1', 'Int
erlis 2', 'OGR_GMT', 'GPKG', 'SQLite', 'ODBC', 'WAsP', 'PGeo', 'MSSQLSpatial', '
PostgreSQL', 'MySQL', 'OpenFileGDB', 'XPlane', 'DXF', 'CAD', 'Geoconcept', 'GeoR
SS', 'GPSTrackMaker', 'VFK', 'PGDUMP', 'OSM', 'GPSBabel', 'SUA', 'OpenAir', 'OGR
_PDS', 'WFS', 'WFS3', 'HTF', 'AeronavFAA', 'Geomedia', 'EDIGEO', 'GFT', 'SVG', '
CouchDB', 'Cloudant', 'Idrisi', 'ARCGEN', 'SEGUKOOA', 'SEGY', 'ODS', 'XLSX', 'El
asticSearch', 'Walk', 'Carto', 'SXF', 'Selafin', 'JML', 'PLSCENES', 'CSW', 'VDV'
, 'GMLAS', 'MVT', 'TIGER', 'AVCBin', 'AVCE00', 'NGW', 'GenBin', 'ENVI', 'EHdr',
'ISCE', 'HTTP']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by :https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/ecw.html

You'll need the ECW SDK which will probably mean that you'll have to compile GDAL yourself.

Specifically: "GDAL supports reading and writing ECW files using the ERDAS ECW/JP2 SDK developed by Hexagon Geospatial (formerly Intergraph, ERDAS, ERMapper). Support is optional and requires linking in the libraries available from the ECW/JP2 SDK Download page."

Comment: I do not understand. Why `gdalinfo` and `gdal_translate` recognize `ECW` but python utilite `gdal2tiles` not recognize?

Comment: I can't confirm, but possibly because gdal2tiles.py is a python file, it might not have been compiled with ECW support, while the .exe's might have been compiled with support. You might want to try using gdal_translate to change the ECW into a different file format and see if that works.

Comment: Usually i donwload gdal from `http://www.gisinternals.com/` and here is `ecw` plugin for gdal. And after install this `exe` utils starts to work with this format. How to change python utilites to they starts to work with  `ecw`. I'd already tried to translate ecw to tiff. But gdal said taht output tiff file will take 500gb of disk space, so this solution not work for me.

Comment: Try: gdal_translate -of GTiff -co “COMPRESS=LZW” -co “PREDICTOR=2” -co “TILED=YES” Path\To\INFILENAME.ecw Path\To\OUTPUT.tiff
This will create a compressed tiff that should take up a lot less space

Comment: In the end i found that all my tries of converting `ecw` into `tif` give a low resolution results. And the idea of this convertation is pointless.

Comment: @KliverMax the LZW compression method is lossless, so the output tiff raster image will have the same cells value and the same resolution of the input raster image.

Answer (score 0):

The ERDAS SDK needs to be licensed, specifically it has to be for server use and writing, while it can be linked in desktop scenarios for reading. And that's probably why it's not supported out of the box.

(This info is already linked in Francis' answer, BTW)

The old 3.3 SDK has a more permissive license but server side usage is still ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, there is a Dockerized installation of GDAL with the old 3.3 SDK available here: https://github.com/DHI-GRAS/ecw2tiff